# Exception sending request initialized lifecycle event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jsf, java-ee-6

I'm getting this error when I try to configure my first application. War Is  generated successfully but when I hit the URL of my project this error appears on the web page and same error appears in console :

**The stack trace**

```
2013-07-20 17:05:49,100 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/testing]] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Exception sending request initialized lifecycle event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request is not an HttpServletRequest: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@2b617c79
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener.requestInitialized(RequestContextListener.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:180)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
2013-07-20 17:06:12,617 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/testing]] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Exception sending request initialized lifecycle event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request is not an HttpServletRequest: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@f4ffab5
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener.requestInitialized(RequestContextListener.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:180)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you don't happen to have the **servlet-api** library in your war. If so, you'll have to remove it as this library is provided by the server.

**Explanation:**
The `HttpServletRequest` is provided by the **servlet-api** library, which is usually loaded by the server (JBoss, Tomcat, etc.)

If the library is also present in your applicatio, it gets loaded multiple time, by different [classloaders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader): the application classloader and the server default classloader.

The thing is, the `HttpServletRequest` loaded by the server cannot be cast to the `HttpServletRequest` loaded by your application, and vice-versa.